# R- Split + list function

Tags: r

Could anyone explain the split and list function in R? I am quite confused how to use them together. For example

```
x <- rnorm(10)
a <- gl(2,5)
b <- gl(5,2)
str(split(x,list(a,b))
```

The result I get is

```
List of 10
$ 1.1: num [1:2] 0.1326 -0.0578
$ 2.1: num(0) 
$ 1.2: num [1:2] 0.151 0.907
$ 2.2: num(0) 
$ 1.3: num -0.393
$ 2.3: num 1.83
$ 1.4: num(0) 
$ 2.4: num [1:2] 0.4266 -0.0116
$ 1.5: num(0) 
$ 2.5: num [1:2] 0.62 1.64
```

How are values in `x` assigned to a level in `list(a,b)`? Why are there some levels without any values and some with many values? I do not see any relation between the values in `x` and the levels of `list(a,b)`. Are they randomly assigned?

Really apreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Have you read `?split`: The second arg is "a ‘factor’ in the sense that as.factor(f) defines the grouping, or *a list of such factors in which case their interaction is used for the grouping.*" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Also `identical(split(x, list(a, b)), split(x, interaction(a, b)))` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `split(x, list(a, b))`, you are basically saying that two `x` values are in the same group if they have the same `a` and `b` value and are in different groups otherwise.

```
list(a, b)
# [[1]]
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
# Levels: 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

We can see that the first two elements in x are going to be in group "1.1" (the group where a=1 and b=1), the next two will be in group 1.2, the next one will be in group 1.3, the next one will be in group 2.3, the next two will be in group 2.4, and the last two will be in group 2.5. This is exactly what we see when we call `split(x, list(a, b))`:

```
split(x, list(a, b))
# $`1.1`
# [1] -0.2431983 -1.5747339
# $`2.1`
# numeric(0)
# $`1.2`
# [1] -0.1058044 -0.8053585
# $`2.2`
# numeric(0)
# $`1.3`
# [1] -1.538958
# $`2.3`
# [1] 0.8363667
# $`1.4`
# numeric(0)
# $`2.4`
# [1]  0.8391658 -1.0488495
# $`1.5`
# numeric(0)
# $`2.5`
# [1]  0.3141165 -1.1813052
```

The reason you have extra empty groups (e.g. group 2.1) is that `a` and `b` have some pairs of values where there are no `x` values. From `?split`, you can read that the way to not include these in the output is with the `drop=TRUE` option:

```
split(x, list(a, b), drop=TRUE)
# $`1.1`
# [1] -0.2431983 -1.5747339
# $`1.2`
# [1] -0.1058044 -0.8053585
# $`1.3`
# [1] -1.538958
# $`2.3`
# [1] 0.8363667
# $`2.4`
# [1]  0.8391658 -1.0488495
# $`2.5`
# [1]  0.3141165 -1.1813052
```